# Abstracting the jquery dialog call to reduce bloat

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to create an abstracted jquery dialog function that i pass parameters into to reduce my overall js bloat. My javascript is currently full of examples such as this:

```
    $(".claim_issue_lb").click(function (e) {

    $(function () {

        $("#dialog-claim").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 240,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Claim Issue": function () {
                    ProcessDealerAction("claim"); //function to be called upon success
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

To address this, I created the following:

```
function LoadDialog(target, height, confirm_button, function_call) {

$(target).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: height,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        confirm_button: function () {
            function_call;
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

}

With the hopes of being able to reduce my dialog calls to the following example:

```
$(".claim_issue_lb").click(function (e) {

    LoadDialog("#dialog-claim", 240, "Claim Issue", ProcessDealerAction("claim"));

});
```

It seems to be working well, except that the confirm dialog pops up and then runs itself without anyone clicking "Yes do it" or "Cancel", and then the dialog auto closes.

I'm not certain how to address this, or if my entire approach is flawed from the ground up.

Comment: can we see some more code? what you have posted does not allow us to help correct the issue you are having.

Comment: @rlemon. It looksl ike he's trying to pass `ProcessDealerAction` as a function literal, but instead is passing the result of the call. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadDialog("#dialog-claim", 240, "Claim Issue", ProcessDealerAction("claim"));`

Will execute `ProcessDealerAction` immediately. You'll need to pass a `function` here, not its result.

```
function LoadDialog(target, height, confirm_button, function_call, function_args) {
...
LoadDialog("#dialog-claim", 240, "Claim Issue", ProcessDealerAction, ["claim"]);
```

or

`LoadDialog("#dialog-claim", 240, "Claim Issue", (new function(){ProcessDealerAction("claim"));}))`

will get you closer to where you need to be. You'll also need to call your callback correctly.

```
 confirm_button: function () {
            function_call();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
```

or if you decide to pass in args separately and not need anonymous functions:

```
 confirm_button: function () {
            function_call.apply(this, [function_args]);
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
```

Comment: I tried the bottom approach and it still auto ran. I'll work on the top one. Thanks.

Comment: for the second solution try function_call.apply(this,[function_args]) i'm not sure why, but this has worked in the past for me ??

Comment: @rlemon your suggestion did it. the other methods were either throwing formatting errors or still running without pause. thanks!